# Applying middleware in Nestjs. Or what is proper use of swagger-ui-express packages in Nestjs?

Tags: swagger, nestjs

I have APIs listening on path /API. (code temporarily is here https://github.com/vit100/nest-middleware-test.

There is middleware (which serves static swagger file) applied for root like this:

```
// app.module.ts------------
import { F1, F2, F3 } from './swaggerMiddleware';

export class AppModule implements NestModule {
  configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer): void | MiddlewareConsumer {
  consumer.apply(F1, F2, F3).exclude('/api').forRoutes('/');
  }
}
// end of app.module.ts------------

//swaggerMiddleware.ts-------------------------

import { Injectable, NestMiddleware, Logger } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Request, Response } from 'express';
import yamljs from 'yamljs';
import swaggerUiExpress from 'swagger-ui-express';

const yamlDoc = yamljs.load(__dirname + '\\swagger.yaml');

@Injectable()
export class F1 implements NestMiddleware {
  use(req: Request, res: Response, next: () => void) {
    if (req.url.includes('api')) {
      return next();
    }
    req.url = req.originalUrl;
    return swaggerUiExpress.serve[0].call(this, req, res, next);
  }
}


@Injectable()
export class F2 implements NestMiddleware {
  use(req: Request, res: Response, next: () => void) {
    if (req.url.includes('api')) {
      return next();
    }
    req.url = req.originalUrl;
    return swaggerUiExpress.serve[1].call(this, req, res, next);
  }
}


@Injectable()
export class F3 implements NestMiddleware {
  use(req: Request, res: Response, next: () => void) {
    if (req.url.includes('api')) {
      return next();
    }
    req.url = req.originalUrl;
    return swaggerUiExpress.setup(yamlDoc).call(this, req, res, next);
  }
}
//end of swaggerMiddleware.ts-------------------------
```

I didn't find another way to integrate swaggerUiExpress. Unfortunately I have to split invocation into separate middleware classes.
Classes, not functions - because `.exclude('/api')` doesn't work with function middleware. Also have to reassign `req.url = req.originalUrl;` as it is lost somewhere...

It started to work, but I don't know. For me it is very fishy...
Or should be another way to serve such logic, like this swagger middleware?

Comment: Have you tried this official way? https://github.com/scottie1984/swagger-ui-express Are you sure you can call two middleware, i.e. `serve`, `setup` on same `req,res,next` objects? I think you have to chain like this `app.use('/', swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(yamlDoc));`

Comment: Yes, I did - it works fine.

But I need to serve external file which is supported/generated by another means and that file is shared between other applications. Thats why I try to use this way.

Comment: yeah, this does look fishy.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a good approach regardless of your use case. You are loading a yaml file on every request, it's going out of scope, getting garbage collected and re-read from the file system for the next request. You should load the file outside the request and serve it from memory. **Edit**: If you need to refresh the file based on changes, you could use `fs.watch`

As to why this doesn't work, you are calling two distinct middleware on the same `req`,`res`, `next` objects. but when you call next on the first middleware it hands off to the next middle-ware that has been chained by the framework and referenced in `next`. By the time your second middleware calls `next`, the framework has begun writing the response as the req-res cycle is over. What you need to do is to chain these middleware yourself by passing the second middleware as the next handler for the first middleware. Like  so,

```
import swaggerUiExpress from 'swagger-ui-express';
import yamljs from 'yamljs';
const yamlDoc = yamljs.load(__dirname + '\\swagger.yaml');

export function swaggerMiddleware(req, res, next) {
 swaggerUiExpress.serve[0](req, res, function (req, res) {
     swaggerUiExpress.setup(yamlDoc)(req, res, next)
 });
);
}
```

Comment: yes and no. yes - it is correct I need to call second middleware in the place where next is. Original question corrected.

no - there is another issue with it. I believe related to the way how nestjs handles it